# Does leaving the Views UI module enabled affect performance?

Tags: views, performance

I noticed that the "Disable Developer Modules" link in the Administration Menu module disabled the Views UI module. I'm under the impression that the purpose of disabling the developer modules is to reduce performance impacts. But I didn't think the Views UI module would have an affect on performance. Does leaving Views UI enabled in production have any performance impact? Is there any other reason to disable this module on a production site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every enabled module affect performance, just for the fact they are loaded, and parsed from PHP. views_ui.module, in the branch 6.x-3.x-dev of Views, is 10355 bytes.
There are then hooks that are invoked from Drupal, even if you are not using anything from the Views UI module, such as [views_ui_help()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views_ui.module/function/views_ui_help/6), [views_ui_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views_ui.module/function/views_ui_menu/6), [views_ui_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views_ui.module/function/views_ui_theme/6), or [views_ui_library_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views_ui.module/function/views_ui_library_alter/7).

Another reason to disable unused modules is avoiding possible security issues.

Comment: Is this still relevant in D8 given the architecture changes? Also you can't *deactivate* modules in 8, but I've also seen a couple of examples of people blacklisting config for Field UI, Views UI etc. from production using [config_split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split)

Comment: Yes, except that Drupal 7 enabled modules are Drupal 8 installed modules, since it is not possible to disable modules on Drupal 8. The _Configuration Split_ module is used when exporting the configuration, so that part of the configuration files are put in a different directory; it is normally used when importing configuration from a development site, to avoid the settings for modules like the ones you list go in the production server.